# Is it better to save data in an XML or a database?

Tags: c#, wpf, simulation, .net-4.5

We develop an airline simulation game, and our current structure saves user data in an XML file (as well as all game data such as airport statistics, aircraft information, etc).

Performance and functionality-wise, what is the best way to store this data on the local machine? I have heard some of both sides but no real concrete or example-backed answers. Although our raw data XMLs are smaller (<150KB), the saved games are quite large (3-10MB) and span several thousand lines of more or less unorganized data.

Thoughts, suggestions, or recommendations?

Comment: How often are you loading/saving the data? How important is it during gameplay? If it is only during startup and specific save, it probably doesn't really matter.

Comment: And do you ever need to actually *query* it, or are you really just saving and loading the whole thing?

Comment: The dedicated usage would be to load and save games. We seem to be riddled with performance problems from calculating game information at the moment, so to reduce save times we may try to do a sort of incremental autosave that adds information which will remain static to the save file when it is created.

Comment: Ever play a game, then browse to the game folder and see all your person save data and such there? Most professional game companies seem to take the 'save it to a file' approach. Have you looked at other similar games to see what they did? Just a thought.

Comment: I've looked at other games (although not particularly recently). I've seen quite a few games that use proprietary formatting for saving their games, but I'm not sure if the performance benefit would justify this in our case.

Comment: If you're just saving and restoring objects that represent the game state, I think you might as well just use XML serialization. I assuming you're compressing the XML stream when you save it? Or use Binary serialization (and probably compress that, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to be able to edit the files by hand you could try using the BinaryFormatter to serialize & deserialize your data, should be a lot faster than the XmlSerializer.

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Child
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class TestClass
    {

        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Property3 { get; set; }
        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TestClass testClass = new TestClass()
            {
                Property1 = 1,
                Property2 = "test",
                Property3 = DateTime.Now,
                Child = new Child()
                {
                     Property1 = "test", 
                }
            };

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, testClass);

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            TestClass deserialized = formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream) as TestClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this best. You can combine this with GZipStream to compress the output, which I bet would make it quite a lot smaller for a large game save.

Comment: Apparently we have tried this in the past, but encountered an issue on serializing an object containing other objects. Any words of wisdom/links to content referencing that? A quick google search didn't show anything incredibly useful

Comment: Should work fine, I've updated the example to show an object containing another object.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data in XML file, then consider a XML Database for it Like Oracle BerkleyDB XML/BaseX/Sedna. You can use DB API for data manipulation and also can use XQuery for querying that XML. Berkley DB XML Database is good in performance.

Also you should use XML Database if your user data, airport statistics etc have information which can vary row to row.

And if your data model is well structured, then you can use open source database like MySql or PostGreSql to handle all your data.

Here, both will work fine with your expected database size for data addition/updation. You should consider your data model for choosing the data repository type.

If you choose XML Database your data access/save code may be reused.

If you choose RDBMS, you should code for your application layer.

Hope, this insight and further study will help you.